# No SplashScreen module on python3 wx Windows

Tags: python-3.x, wxwidgets, splash-screen

I am trying to create a Splash Screen in python3 using wx following [this](https://wiki.wxpython.org/SplashScreen) tutorial.

According to them, there should exist a SplashScreen attribute under wx, but I get an Error saying that wx does not have attribute SplashScreen.

Also in this [Link](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.SplashScreen.html), it is mentioned that SplashScreen should be available under **adv**(wx.adv.SplashScreen). But no luck here, too. It gives an error saying that wx has no attribute adv.

So, how can I create a splash screen in python 3 using wx?

BTW, I am using wxPython (4.0.0b2), python 3.5.3 and Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I would do is update wxPython, If that does not work then reinstall wx.

Comment: Did that. No change.

Comment: @S.S.H, you will probably have better luck posting to wxPython ML...

Comment: Did it.
Hope someone answers.
Thanks